# Using a custom allocator for a given templatized type by default in stl containers

Tags: templates, c++11, stl, eigen, partial-specialization

My particular use case is to try and cut back on the boiler-plate code required to use stl containers with Eigen for some of the newer developers I work with, but this question could be applied more generally.  Idiomatic C++11 is preferred.

Given the following:

```
template<int i, int i> MyClass { ... };
template<class C> MyAllocator { ... };
```

How would you write a specialization of std::vector (or any of the other stl container types) which would use MyAllocator by default when the Value type of the vector was MyClass?

I was thinking the answer, in the case of Eigen's Matrix class, might look something like this:

```
namespace std{
  template<typename _S, int _A, int _B, int _C, int _D, int _E>
  vector< Eigen::Matrix<_S, _A, _B, _C, _D, _E> > :
    public vector< 
      Eigen::Matrix<_S, _A, _B, _C, _D, _E>, 
      Eigen::aligned_allocator<
        Eigen::Matrix<_S, _A, _B, _C, _D, _E>
      >
    >
  {};
}
```

This isn't even close to compiling, but I think conveys what I'm trying to do. I'd really like to avoid having to use the EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION, or any approach that requires explicit specialization on every supported permutation of the type.

One alternative approach I've considered is using template aliasing like so:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  template<typename T>
  vector = std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T>>;

  template<typename _K, typename _V, typename _C = std::less<_K>>
  using map = std::map<_K, _V, _C, Eigen::aligned_allocator<std::pair<_K, _V>>>;
}
```

This has the potential for misuse, but does significantly reduce boilerplate code. Is there anything in the C++11 or C++14 standards that would enable this type of behavior? I'm assuming it was impossible prior to C++11 since I imagine the Eigen community would have done it already otherwise.

**Edit/Answer:**

After some further thought & discussion with colleges, what I was trying to do is probably a bad idea, since it leads to surprising behavior (std::allocator behaving as Eigen::aligned_allocator in some cases)

The best option seems to be the template aliases since it makes it clear what's happening. Specializing the containers, or even specializing std::allocator would lead to people looking at the code and thinking we were not using the containers correctly if they were not aware of the weird stuff we'd done.  I'd still like to see Eigen improve the allocator requirements using some of the newer c++11 features but that should probably happen at a library level.  If anyone knows how to specialize std::allocator_traits> to use the aligned_allocator I'd love to know about it, but for now the template aliases seem like the most understandable (and easiest to implement) option.

Comment: "How would you write a specialization of std::vector (or any of the other stl container types) which would use MyAllocator by default when the Value type of the vector was MyClass?" — A specialization of `vector` would mean that `MyClass` has already been specified, so there's no "when" any more. Also, you have shown `MyClass` as a template, not a class. It sounds like you want either a template alias `using MyVector<i1,i2> = std::vector< MyClass<i1,i2 >, MyAllocator< MyClass<i1,i2> > >` or a user-defined specialization of `std::allocator<MyClass<i1,i2> >`.

Comment: The specialization of std::allocator is indeed more in line with what I wanted, however even that wouldn't be sufficient for eigen, since I'd also need to specialize std::allocator<std::pair<_T,MyClass>> and std::allocator<std::pair<MyClass,_T>>, and then god only knows what for tuples or other container types...